# How to disable or change automatic session locking in ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my Toshiba C55 Satellite. I'm a total Newbie to Linux.  My laptop screen goes blank after 10 minutes and I have to move mouse and log in again using my username.

Can this be stopped?  I know it does this because I haven't used the system for 10 minutes but there must be somewhere in settings to change this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in Dash type `Brightness and Lock` :

You will see `Lock screen after` **-->** **adjust** as you want , you can `disable` lock screen .

```
Uncheck Require my password when waking from suspend .
```

Answer (score 0):

At the top right corner of the screen, you'll see the battery icon.
click it. Click "power settings..."
You do the setting in "suspend when inactive for"

Additionally, below where it states:
Tips: screen brightness.....

Click to change settings on DIM, SCREEN LOCK, & Uncheck Box below to not require password if you wish...